# Can anyone help me with the Excel formula for the below data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: excel scrrenshot]

In the above image, I need to populate the value as described in the `Creator`
   column... I have the data till value column..

Comment: what is the logic to populate those values  ?

Comment: Row 3: a1 has value "aa" , so creator "a1", Now  ROW 4: "aa" changed to "aa1" by  "b1"  but the original creator is "a1" so I need a1 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Column B is always empty for new entries, and Column C is always populated, then this should work:

```
=IF(B2="",A2,INDEX(D:D,MATCH(B2,C:C,0)))
```

Enter the formula in cell D2 and then fill down.

Comment: column B is not empty, It contains some values

Comment: David M  , unable to apply the formula